# winston logger writing in both files

Tags: express, winston

This is writing in both log file success and error.log if i called with log.fail I would expect it should write in error-date.log file. I don't know what's wrong here

```
const fs = require('fs');
var winston = require('winston');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const logDir = 'logs';

if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}

const now = new Date();
var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
            filename: `${logDir}/success-%DATE%.log`,
            timestamp: now,
            datePattern: 'DD-MM-yyyy',
            prepend: true,
            json: false,
            level: 'info',
        }),
        new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
            filename: `${logDir}/error-%DATE%.log`,
            timestamp: now,
            datePattern: 'DD-MM-yyyy',
            prepend: true,
            json: false,
            level: 'error',
        }),
    ],
    exitOnError: false,
});
const log = {
    fail: function (ee) {
        logger.error(`${now.toISOString()} - ${JSON.stringify(ee)}`);
    },
    success: function (ee) {
        logger.info(`${now.toISOString()} - ${JSON.stringify(ee)}`);
    },
};
module.exports = log;
```

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. When you define a level it considers it as priority level & logs any log (with higher priority) than that.

Comment: what can i do for separate log for error and success